# Fourier coefficient $ \hat{f}(n) $ and $\|f\|_1$

Tags: normed-spaces, fourier-series

If $ \hat{f}(n) $ is Fourier coefficient of $ f $, show that $ |\hat{f}(n)| \leq\|f\|_1$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Fourier coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\hat f(n)| = \left|\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}\,dx\right|\le\int_0^1|f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}|\,dx = \int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx = \|f\|_1$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally: $$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\,dx.$$